# Button still have attribute disabled="" in the test after providing all the field values and there is no error

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am trying to test the disabled property of a form (implemented using react-hook-form) button as below

```
it('Can submit form when all mandatory fields are filled', async () => {
    const { getByLabelText, getByTestId, getByText } = setup() // rendering component
    const company = getByLabelText('companyName_label')
    const street = getByLabelText('companyStreetNumber_label')
    const zip = getByLabelText('companyZip_label')
    const city = getByLabelText('companyCity_label')
    const submitButton = getByText('forms.submit')
    
    fireEvent.change(company, { target: { value: 'Company name' } })
    fireEvent.change(street, { target: { value: 'Street name' } })
    fireEvent.change(zip, { target: { value: '123456' } })
    fireEvent.change(city, { target: { value: 'City name' } })

    await waitFor(() => {
      screen.debug(submitButton.closest('button'))
      expect(submitButton.closest('button')).toHaveProperty('disabled', false)
    })
  })
```

Getting below in the console because of screen.debug

```
      <button
        aria-disabled="true"
        class="css-1igmvq8-OnboardingDetails"
        data-identifier="submit"
        disabled=""
      >
        <span
          class="button-label css-1sj01yp-B"
        >
          forms.submit
        </span>
      </button>
```

And I am getting an error as below

```
    expect(received).toHaveProperty(path, value)

    Expected path: "disabled"

    Expected value: false
    Received value: true
```

Also tried testing as below:

```
    expect(element).not.toBeDisabled()

    Received element is disabled:
      <button
        aria-disabled="true"
        class="css-1igmvq8- 
        OnboardingDetails"
        data-identifier="submit-onboarding"
        disabled=""
      />
```

Before I made below two changes, this test was passing:

1. Changed the mode of the form from "all" to "onBlur"
2. Added an async validation on one of the fields.

Also, I consoled errors from the form, it was empty.
Any help/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have asynchronous validation to any of your fields? if yes then I have to say when using asynchronous validation, the validation process may take some time to complete, assuming your asynchronous validation function is called **validateAsyncField**.
`await waitFor(() => expect(validateAsyncField).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));`

Even you can add a timout to make sure all promises are resolved.
`await waitFor(() => {}, { timeout: 500 });`